# TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to change the value of `<p class="dice1"><p>` in html via javascript, but nothing changes when I run the code.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="">
    <p class="dice1"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="dice.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

www  App Brewery  com

```
document.getElementByClassName("dice1").innerHTML = "your dice number is 6"
```

Comment: I tried  document.getElementsByClassName("dice1").innerHTML = "your dice number is 6"   too, it still not working

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('dice1')[0].innerHTML = 'your dice number is 6'`

Comment: @aerial301 it is working!! Why do I have to add [0] while I only have 1 "dice1'' in my codes?

Comment: @ĐứcSeven because document.getElementsByClassName() returns a list. With `[0]` you retrieve the first item from that list. Indexes start at 0

Comment: @milt_on got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method doesn't return specified element, but list of elements.
Try to filter list which it return to get element which u'd like to edit.